# rails simple_form boolean with text label correctly implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, boolean, simple-form

Trying to make a boolean with a label left but it fails,
I could not find any complete example in the documentation online.

Currently Im using:

```
  = f.input_field :remember_me, as: :boolean,
                  :input_html => { :checked => true },
                  :inline_label => true

  = f.label "Remember me"
  %br
```

[image]

Comment: So put first `f.label` and then `f.input_field`?

Answer (score 0):

```
= f.label "Remember me"   
= f.input_field :remember_me, as: :boolean, :input_html => { :checked => true }, :inline_label => true
```